# Ubuntu 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: resolv.conf

I have this problem when I try to connect to the internet. The real problem is that I want to update my system, then I realized that I can't access the internet. I modified my resolv.conf file by setting up the nameserver 8.8.8.8 but when pinging I still have the same error. I really need your help, I've been on it for days. I tried to apply what was given as a resolution to a question similar to mine but it doesn't work. please help me please